# How to revert alternatives to default python2 on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, python3, python-2.7

So on my 18.04 I upgraded my python3 to 3.7 (which build a meld dependency) and did this:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
```

which made the python command default to python 3 but not am realizing it is breaking a number of utilities such as our software build, thg and my lock screen, networking. I'd like to revert but have discovered this command does not revert as desired:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
```

How would I revert my system to it's original state of python launching python2?

Is this not recommended or will there be any side effects if I did this route?

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /etc/alternatives/python
```

Comment: The usual interactive usage would be `sudo update-alternatives --config python`, then follow the on-screen instructions - did you try that?

Comment: Wish I saw this a little earlier I had deleted /etc/alternatives/python and created a link to /usr/bin/python2. Hope there are no side effects from my manual approach.